# Matlab: get data values, from a curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have created arrays of `x_data` and `y_data` values in matlab and plot them like:

```
plot(x_data,y_data,'o')
```

Now I fit a 4th order polynomial to the data.

How can I get the `x_data` and `y_data` corresponding to this 4th order polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) for Polynomial evaluation.

`y = polyval(p,x)` returns the value of a polynomial of degree n evaluated at x. The input argument p is a vector of length n+1 whose elements are the coefficients in descending powers of the polynomial to be evaluated.